# How to use dates in Django model?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

When using DateField, I keep getting this error after running `migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to time without time zone
LINE 1: ...TER COLUMN "create_time" TYPE time USING "create_time"::time
```

I tried to use `create_time = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)`

I've also tried `create_time = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())`

And get the same error.

Some answers I've read suggest editing my postgres database. However I did not get this error before - I originally had `auto_now=True` instead of `auto_now_add=True`. This error only came up after I changed that. I tried to change it back to `auto_now=True`, and I still get this error upon running `migrate`.

I also removed the DateField entirely from my model, and when running `migrate` I STILL get the error. Is it possible I need to reset something, so that I'm migrating the most updated model?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Did you import these in models and in views.py 
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone 
import datetime
from datetime import date

Comment: @MuhammedBilal yes

Comment: can you try this                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                            date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: @MuhammedBilal, I tried that just now but I'm still getting the error

Comment: @MuhammedBilal how do I flush it? Would it be just the migrations I'm flushing?

Comment: All data will be deleted then again you have to make models and make migrations

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedBilal - I ended up deleting all the unapplied migrations that were giving the error, and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: You are welcome .Vote up if it is helpful